# Substring a SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, substring

I have a question on SQL I'm using oracle 11g, I want to know if it is possible to do this:

For example I have this SQL QUERY:

```
SELECT DC.DASHBOARD_UID 
FROM   DASHBOARD_SAVE DS 
       LEFT JOIN DASHBOARD_COLOR DC 
           ON DC.DASHBOARD_UID = DS.DASHBOARD_UID
```

I want to know if it possible to make a substring of this query to get these informations:

`COL_NAME: DC.DASHBOARD_UID
TABLE_NAME: DASHBOARD_COLOR DC
JUNCTURE_NAME:  LEFT JOIN DASHBOARD_COLOR DC ON DC.DASHBOARD_UID = DS.DASHBOARD_UID`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in a simple case like yours, something like the following code might do the job.

However, in realistic situations, things can get much more complicated (e.g. inline views, `WHERE` clause, unions, ...) so you'd end up with writing your own parser. If that's what you want, go ahead. I had to do it when I was a student (not with SQL, though) and it was interesting.

Here you go (`temp` CTE is used to remove new line characters and multiple spaces):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'SELECT DC.DASHBOARD_UID, DS.SOME_COL
  3             FROM   DASHBOARD_SAVE DS
  4             LEFT JOIN DASHBOARD_COLOR DC
  5               ON DC.DASHBOARD_UID = DS.DASHBOARD_UID'
  6             from dual
  7    ),
  8  temp as
  9    (select regexp_replace(UPPER(replace(col, chr(10), '')), '\s{2,}', ' ') col
 10     from test
 11    )
 12  select
 13    trim(substr(col, instr(col, 'SELECT') + 7,
 14                     instr(col, 'FROM') - instr(col, 'SELECT') - 7
 15               )) column_list,
 16    --
 17    trim(regexp_replace(substr(col, instr(col, 'FROM') + 4,
 18                                    instr(col, 'JOIN') - instr(col, 'FROM') - 4
 19                              ),
 20                        'LEFT|RIGHT|CROSS', '')) table_name,
 21    --
 22    regexp_substr(col, '(LEFT|RIGHT|CROSS JOIN) .+') juncture_name
 23  From temp;

COLUMN_LIST                   TABLE_NAME        JUNCTURE_NAME
----------------------------- ----------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------
DC.DASHBOARD_UID, DS.SOME_COL DASHBOARD_SAVE DS LEFT JOIN DASHBOARD_COLOR DC ON DC.DASHBOARD_UID = DS.DASHBOARD_UID

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks exactly whats I need , just I want to know If i can cut each SELECT on a row , and get his own Juncture  ?

Comment: @Littlefoot i guess this is way too manual spool is a better way and then can manipulate the results

Comment: DEVLOGIN, as I said: everything is possible, it just depends on how much effort you want to put into it. @Himanshu, I think you misunderstood the question. It is not about *data* query returns, but how to parse the query itself.

Comment: @Littlefoot Ok if you say that it is possible I'm going to do this , I was worried about impossible script

Comment: Good luck! I'd say you'll need it.

Comment: @Littlefoot I guess if its related to parsing then it is easy i guess just `substr('select query', Instr(col, '') ` as you did above. But this isnt dynamic I still think we can implement this logic after storing via spool in a file the same query and then reading and parsing from the same file via above logic. This would then be dynamic

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like
`SPOOL filename`. Spooling writes to your respective file whatever gets printed on the sql console after spool command as I see as per your query above you dont want to get the data but design creation as o/p